# What is Klass & KlassKlass

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, permgen

What is `Klass` & `KlassKlass` in JVM Hotspot Implementation?

As far as I understood from the article [Presenting the Perm Generation](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation), `Klass` is the internal representation of a Java class (let's say `A`) & it will hold the basic information about the structure of the class including the bytecode. It will be stored as an object itself. Every object of the class A will have a pointer to the internal representation `Klass` present in PermGen

KlassKlass is the internal representation of the `Klass` class itself. Why does `KlassKlass` is needed? What extra information is it storing?

Also, a `KlassKlass's` `Klass` pointer points to itself, I didn't understand it either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Permanent Generation a.k.a permgen is the referred to the place where all the class related information is stored. It is occasionally referred as method-area.

Lets take an example of the following code:

```
public class Parent
{
    ...
}
```

Here:

- `new Parent()` is an object of `Parent` class.
- `(new Parent()).getClass()` refers to `Klass` of Parent. The reference type for this object would be `java.lang.Class<Parent>`. This would store the information about `Parent`'s annotations, constructors, fields, methods, its inheritance (superclass, interfaces) etc
- KlassKlass would be `(new Parent()).getClass().getClass()`. The reference type for this object would be `java.lang.Class<java.lang.Class>`. This defines the information about `java.lang.Class`'s annotations, constructors, fields, methods, its inheritance (superclass, interfaces), etc.

Theoretically, this chain could go on but KlassKlassKlass would be same as KlassKlass.

Inshort, KlassKlass means that you would have one `java.lang.Class` object which defines the behavior of `java.lang.Class` itself.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a good general understanding of storage management in HotSpot. To get some more specific details it's a good idea to go to the horse's mouth - in this case the developers of HotSpot. [This page](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/StorageManagement.html) is their description of the storage management system.

In situations where I want to find out what some code does I try and find the code and read it. In this case we can find an implementation of the KlassKlass class [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/jvm/hotspot/oops/KlassKlass.java). This doesn't seem to add an extra information on top of [Klass](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/jvm/hotspot/oops/Klass.java#Klass) - which is very interesting to look at. Note that `KlassKlass` extends `Klass`.

So why do we need it? Well, we can draw out the `Klass` hierarchy of a particular program as a tree where one `Klass` describes another. Everything needs a description but we cannot keep going like this forever, we need to find a [*fixed point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29) where the thing we use to describe something is itself - so we can stop!

So, in summary `KlassKlass` doesn't do anything more useful than existing. It needs to exist but its existence is reasonably uninteresting.