# What is shadow$_klass_ on Android Debug mode?

Tags: android, json, string, kotlin, debugging

I'm trying debugging and checking var that type is "String?".

`private var ch_name : String? = null`

I added it on the start of the class and when I turn on to debugging mode, It becomes infinite.
`shadow$_klass_` has `shadow$_klass_` and it also has `shadow$_klass_`.
I just wanted to see what is the result of ch_name and edit to test value but couldn't.

I searched on Google but still dunno how to find the real value of ch_name. How can I check it?

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: nothing else, and no code error on there. It is just simple nullable string file and I'm having question of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933888/what-are-the-shadow-klass-and-shadow-monitor-variables-for-in-java-lang

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the 'shadow$\_klass\_' and 'shadow$\_monitor\_' variables for in java.lang.Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933888/what-are-the-shadow-klass-and-shadow-monitor-variables-for-in-java-lang)

Comment: Oooooooooooh why I couldn't found it!!! really really yeah that is! thank you so much!